# How to returns a corresponding value in a table based on user input

Tags: vba

I have a table of values and am trying to take in user input for a date, then return the value in a cell on the same row as that date.

This is the code I ended up using:

```
Sub CorrespondingIDNumber()
'Finds the ID number based on the entered travel date

Dim NumRows As Integer, i As Integer, IDNum() As Variant, MatchingDate As Integer
Dim NumSpots As Integer

NumSpots = 0
BookingDate = InputBox("What date would you like to check for?", "Nespor")
MatchingDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("E:E"), BookingDate)
NumRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("E:E"))
ReDim IDNum(MatchingDate)
For i = 1 To NumRows
    If BookingDate = Range("E" & i) Then
        IDNum(NumSpots + 1) = Range("B" & i)
        NumSpots = NumSpots + 1
    Else
End If
Next i
MsgBox ("Here are the customer ID numbers of the customers who booked on " & BookingDate & "."), vbOKOnly, "Nespor"
For i = 1 To NumSpots
    MsgBox (IDNum(i))
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: VLOOKUP() can do that.

Comment: Are you having problems?  If so, showing us the code you are attempting to use will help us help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Heyo! I absolutely recommend using a combination of the Match and Index functions to do this. VLOOKUP is rather limited in comparison (no offense Tim!).

You use Match to search for the date in the appropriate date column. This returns the row number in which that date was found. Then you use the Index formula to pull a value from a different column at that row number that was returned with the match formula.

Essentially it's..."Find a value in one column and tell me what row it's at. Now pull a value from a different column at that same row." AKA "Find the thing and tell me what's next to it."

It is often a difficult concept to grasp at first but once you get it down it is life changing.

Here's a good article.
https://www.deskbright.com/excel/using-index-match/

Hope that helps =)

Comment: This post is kinda banter-ey.  Can you include some example code rather than referring people to an off-site resource?

Comment: Really need to see some code from Op to really give good examples

Answer (score 0):

```
Option explicit

Sub ValueOnSameRowAsDate()

Dim Input as string
Input = application.inputbox("Enter date in YYYY-MM-DD format.",Type:=2)

If Len(input) > 0 then

If isdate(input) then

With Thisworkbook.worksheets(SHEETNAME)

Dim DateInput as date
Dateinput = cdate(input)

Dim DateFound as range
Set DateFound = .cells.find dateinput,,xlformulas,xlwhole,xlbyrows,xlnext

If not (DateFound is nothing) then
Msgbox("Value is: " & .cells(datefound.row, "A"). Value2) 'I have put column A as an example, change it to whatever you need.
Else
Msgbox("Entered date was not found on sheet. Exiting procedure.")
End if

Else
Msgbox("Input not recognised as valid date. Exiting procedure.")
End if

End if

End sub
```

Excel worksheet functions (INDEX+MATCH, VLOOKUP, etc.) alone should be able to do what you've described, without any need for VBA.

That said, code needs you to replace SHEETNAME and column "A" in the code with actual values as per your workbook -- and communicates the value via a message box. Could be better to change the Sub to Function, as it returns a value.

Untested and written on mobile, sorry for bad formatting.